# Java print one console line full with X

Tags: java, printing, cmd, console

I want to print X's to one full console line as a Seperator but how do i know when the the line is "full" so it doesnt pirnt into the next line.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is never really "full", you need to set that length yourself and break it using '\n' its based on the size of the console window and other variables outside of your control.

Comment: Show us your code, at least show your desired output

Comment: how do i get the console size. I want it to show like this https://pastebin.com/n8dSNrqw